# Customize org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs with Gradle eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse

I try to customize some Eclipse preferences for a specific set of projects. More specifically, using `gradle eclipse`, I want to generate the *.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs* file with some specific entries. For example :
`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingOverrideAnnotation=ignore`

I understand that I have to do [something like that](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseJdt.html), but I still have some difficulties to make it work (and I'm not really familiar with the Gradle Groovy language).

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a working build.gradle :

```
eclipse {
  jdt {
    file {
      withProperties { properties ->
        // set properties for the file org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
        properties['org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingOverrideAnnotation'] = 'ignore'
        properties['org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.uncheckedTypeOperation'] = 'ignore'
      }
    }
  }
}
```